# SFTP connection fails with "500 Syntax error, command unrecognized"

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp

I've been trying to connect to an FTP server using `sftp`. The connection closes with *500 Syntax error, command unrecognized*:

```
...
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 220-Welcome To FTP Server

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 220-....

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 220 ....

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 421 Login time exceeded. Closing control connection.

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

[Screenshot of the complete verbose output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb34d.png)

Was wondering what will be the possible error and what the fix would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The welcome message is an FTP thing. The same with *"500 Syntax error, command unrecognized"* – That's an FTP error message. There's nothing like that in the SFTP protocol.

Their server responds with FTP protocol on the SSH/SFTP 22 port. It can also be FTPS vs. SFTP confusion. The FTPS is secure extension of the FTP. While the SFTP is different thing.

---

You cannot connect to an FTP server using an SFTP client. The FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols. Use an FTP client, like the common Linux commandline `ftp`.

As the FTP server listens on a non-standard port (22), you have to do something like:

```
$ ftp
ftp> open example.com 22
```